# Service worker no arranca en mi página (Django)

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema con el service worker de mi página. Lo he probado de manera local en mi computador y ha funcionado correctamente, mostrándome la página offline.

Al momento de hacer la configuración en el hosting o en la página subida a internet no me reconoce o no encuentra el service worker, es más, en consola no muestra ni un error ni rastros de encontrar el archivo.

Estoy trabajando con Django.

---

En esta parte cargo PWA ya instalado y puesto en el array de installed_apps del settings de django, y luego agrego el tag de pwa.

```
{% load pwa %}
{% progressive_web_app_meta %}
```

Luego, en settings agrego la ruta de dónde se encuentra mi archivo serviceworker.js

```
PWA_SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'serviceworker.js')
```

También se agrega en url.py el url de PWA.

```
path('', include('pwa.urls')),
```

Finalmente tengo el archivo serviceworker.js en la raiz de mi proyecto, al nivel donde se encuentra manage.py con la siguiente configuración.

```
var CACHE_NAME = 'my-site-cache-v1';
var urlsToCache = [
'/',
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
// Perform install steps
event.waitUntil(
  caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
    .then(function(cache) {
      console.log('Opened cache');
      return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {

        return fetch(event.request)
         .catch(function(rsp) {
           return response;
        });


       })
    );
 });
```

Estoy trabajando con el host de PythonAnyWhere, dicho anteriormente, de forma local en mi computador el servicio funciona correctamente.

Comment: Bienvenido a la plataforma, no es necesario usar imágenes (salvo ciertos casos), en este te recomiendo editar y colocar el código como texto

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Normalmente para usa PWA se necesita de manera estricta usar protocolo https

Comment: @RimuruTempest muchas gracias, era eso!!